# Write a file bit by bit

Tags: c++, file, binary, fstream

Basically I'm tryng to read a file, change the last bit each 4 bit sequence, then read the changed file and revert it to the original.
es
test1.bin -> test2.bin -> test3.bin
00011100 -> 00001101 -> 00011100
However, while the second file is ok, the third one changes a bit every 8 instead of 4. This is the

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
    ifstream f("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream f_o("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test2.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
    char c,app;

    int rund=0;
    while (f.get(c)){
        app=c;
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){
            if(rund==3){ //it's the 4th bit, I change it
                rund=0;
                if(((c >> i) & 1) == 0)  app |= 1 << i; //if it's 0 i change to 1
                else  app |= 0 << i;
                }   
            else  rund += 1;
        }
        f_o.put(app); 
    }

    f.close();
    f_o.close();

    ifstream f2("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test2.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream f_o2("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test3.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

    rund=0;
    while (f2.get(c)){
        app=c;
        for (int i = 7; i >= 0; i--){ 
            if(rund==3){
                rund=0;
                if(((c >> i) & 1) == 0)  app |= 1 << i;
                else  app |= 0 << i;
                } 
            else  rund += 1;     
        }
        f_o2.put(app); 
    }

}
```

Comment: Narrow down your problem to something more specific. This is called "debugging".

Comment: I got a file named test.bin with some characters inside, as I said in the post, I want to modify it's bits (in this case I revert a bit every 4, if it's 1 it becomes 0 and vice-versa) and then be able to revert it (in this case i do the same with test2.bit), but test3.bin changed a bit only every 8 instead of every 4

Comment: Yes. Narrow down your problem to something more specific, using the technique known as "debugging". Your resulting [MCVE] should have like 4-8 lines in it (yet still be a complete C++ program). Odds are good, though, that the act of producing this MCVE will reveal the problem to you before you need to post here about it. That's part of the purpose.

Comment: Why don't you just use `c2 ^= 0x11;` ?

Comment: I _am_ helping you; you just don't know it yet. :)

Comment: Oh I see you're right, gimme a minute

Comment: Should be minimal now

Comment: @KIIV What does that do?

Comment: @alteration it's a bitwise XOR operation, and taking a while to understand it would reduce the length of this code by....bignum%.  Using xors you can flip those bits 1) without looping over them and 2) using the same operation regardless of whether the bit is currently 1 or 0 (using xor you can 'flip' the state of bits).

Comment: Oh nice that works like a charm! Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

KIIV already effectively gave you the (incredibly-comparatively-simple) solution, so I'll just show it in action and explain why it works (I can't resist, the code reduction here is just too beautiful, and I'm not ashamed to admit that I have a love affair with xor.)

New code:

```
int main(int argc, char** argv) {   
    ifstream f("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream f_o("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test2.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);
    char c;

    while (f.get(c))
        f_o.put(c ^ 0x11);

    f.close();
    f_o.close();

    ifstream f2("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test2.bin", ios::binary | ios::in);
    ofstream f_o2("C:\\Users\\simon\\Desktop\\test\\test3.bin", ios::binary | ios::out);

    while (f2.get(c))
        f_o2.put(c ^ 0x11);   
}
```

**Bitwise Exclusive Or (XOR)**

The operator ^ performs a bitwise exclusive or, aka 'XOR' operation.  It works on a bit-by-bit (bitwise!) basis as follows:

```
0 ^ 0 -> 0
0 ^ 1 -> 1
1 ^ 0 -> 1
1 ^ 1 -> 0
```

In other words, `A ^ B` is 1 if *one and only one* of A, B are 1. Hence the 'exclusive' or.

**Bit Flipping with ^**

Xor is a singularly-interesting bitwise op. Other interesting properties aside, it's the perfect tool for when you need to 'flip' the state of a bit (that is, map a 1 to 0 or a 0 to 1).

Suppose I take `A ^ 1`.  If A is 0, then I have `0 ^ 1 = 1`.  If A is 1, then I have `1 ^ 1 = 0`. So you see, if I xor a bit with 1, I effectively 'flip' the bit.

OTOH, suppose I take `A ^ 0`.  If A is 0, then I have `0 ^ 0 = 0`.  If A is 1, then I have `1 ^ 0 = 1`.  In other words, `A ^ 0 = A`!

This is a perfect situation...we can construct a bitstring to xor with your byte, and each bit in that bitstring will determine whether or not the corresponding bit in your byte gets flipped!

**0x11**

The only remaining thing to understand is how to create the value needed to flip the bits you want.  You want to flip the 4th and 8th bits.  So we need to construct `00010001`.  If you know hex, it's immediately clear that this is `0x11`. If not, use an online converter, and then go learn hexadecimal after you've finished this project..voila :)

Comment: Very complete and exhaustive explanation, thank you sir